# REPOST: Failed to get FIS auth token

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get token using below line of code but getting error as you can see console output. I have done this a long time ago and it worked perfectly. I don't know what is the issue now. Can anyone help me with this issue.

var token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();

```
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973): Failed to get FIS auth token
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later.
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:5)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:8)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.setDefaultAttributesToBundle(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@23.0.0:10)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.startRpc(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@23.0.0:1)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.getToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@23.0.0:1)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$blockingGetToken$9$com-google-firebase-messaging-FirebaseMessaging(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@23.0.0:1)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.start(Unknown Source:6)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.RequestDeduplicator.getOrStartGetTokenRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@23.0.0:6)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@23.0.0:7)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$getToken$3$com-google-firebase-messaging-FirebaseMessaging(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@23.0.0:1)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$$ExternalSyntheticLambda10.run(Unknown Source:4)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:2)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973): Caused by: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later.
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.createFirebaseInstallation(FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:158)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.registerFidWithServer(FirebaseInstallations.java:533)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCallIfNecessary(FirebaseInstallations.java:388)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doRegistrationOrRefresh$2$FirebaseInstallations(FirebaseInstallations.java:377)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at com.google.firebase.installations.-$$Lambda$FirebaseInstallations$VZq1h0TBcWNH8Y5yY86ujrFFyLo.run(Unknown Source:4)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/FirebaseMessaging(29973):     ... 1 more
E/flutter (29973): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_messaging/unknown] java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
E/flutter (29973): #0      MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.getToken
package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:229
E/flutter (29973): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29973): #1      _HomeState.getToken
package:smart_car_parking/…/Home/home.dart:30
E/flutter (29973): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem Solved: I didn't added the new SHA1 key in GCP

Comment: For those wondering, that is Google Cloud Platform. Mine got working after I set it to a location in the firebase console settings. The setting is called "Default GCP resource location"

Answer (score 0):

Delete your current json file, get a new one. Sync project with gradle files and then clean your project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).